# jQuery plugin if else clause not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, clause

I'm writing a jQuery plugin and I am trying to do this:

```
$(this).height>=options.maxHeight ? 
$(this).css({overflow:"auto"}) : 
$(this).css({overflow:"hidden"})
```

however it's not working, I have used this method in my javascript before.

This works how it should, just i was trying to use little code as possible.

```
if($(this).height()>=options.maxHeight)
{
     $(this).css({overflow:"auto"});
}
else
{
     $(this).css({overflow:"hidden"});
}
```

Comment: Aren't you forgetting the () in the $(this).height ?

Comment: What Mario said. Also, "little code as possible" is not automatically better. I think the original version was clearer.

Comment: ahhh! I didn't even notice that, thanks! I have no idea how I removed it.

Comment: But if you do want to go for as little code as possible, move the conditional inside the call to css. Like `$(this).css({overflow: $(this).height >= options.maxHeight ? 'auto' : 'hidden'})`

Comment: yeah thanks that does make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
$(this).height() >= options.maxHeight ? 
$(this).css({overflow:"auto"}) : 
$(this).css({overflow:"hidden"})
```

You forgot the `()` in `.height()`.

You could also use this:

```
$(this).css({overflow: $(this).height() >= options.maxHeight ? 'auto' : 'hidden'});
```